# mathematical terms with fractions and variables - usage in daily life?

Tags: applications, philosophy

what usage do algebraic fractions (monomial or polynomial) have in our life? Are there specific professions that deal with them now and then? Where exactly in technology do they have their very own place?

What I'm looking for is very concrete examples.

Just for clearification: with algebraic fractions (monomial or polynomial) I mean terms such as:

$T_1(x)= \frac{3x + 5}{x^2-7}; T_2(x)=\frac{5}{3x-1} $ etc.

Comment: A lot of high precision computing is based on approximating transcendental functions in a way which involves rational functions (among other things). They also arise in the process of solving certain differential equations (e.g. the logistic equation). However, what you are meant to take away in precalculus is basically how to think about asymptotes, without all the extra complexity associated with transcendental functions.

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Do you have some concrete examples for me? :)

Comment: In addition these are important in the construction of fields throughout all algebra. In particular in algebraic number theory and therefore cryptography.

Comment: Examples of my first point will show up in essentially any implementation of a standard transcendental function, for instance in a standard implementation of $\sin$. The technique is called Pade approximation. Also, more fundamentally, just the algebra required to *deal* with rational functions shows up in many other guises even when the numerator and denominator aren't actually polynomials.

Comment: Frankly, fractions and understanding how to manipulate these are so basic and fundamental that I doubt you can find *any* technology that involves math that doesn't use them at some level....

Comment: @T.Bongers I agree, but I'm not sure how/where to find, let's say, computer language examples that involve them and there reason etc.

Comment: The correct term is 'rational' functions--the 'ratios' of polynomial functions. Anything from the transmission of electrical power to the design of electronic circuits requires the use of Laplace transforms. Laplace transforms of periodic functions require rational functions. Take a look at the Wikipedia page and you will see their necessity for electrical applications. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform